# Power BI SUMX() with an AND Statement Q

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do I add a AND to my SUMX() statement?  My current code is:

```
Enquiry Excluded Amt = 
SUMX (
    FILTER ( _enquiries, _enquiries[_GUID] = _2018_Budget[_GUID] ),
    _enquiries[Amount (Enq)]
)
```

But I want an AND statement added into the SUMX()

```
Enquiry Excluded Amt = 
SUMX (
    FILTER ( _enquiries, _enquiries[_GUID] = _2018_Budget[_GUID] ),
    _enquiries[Amount (Enq)] AND _enquiries[Excluded] = TRUE()
)
```

The above doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `&&` allows for combining conditions in a filter. Like this, for example:

```
Enquiry Excluded Amt = 
SUMX (
    FILTER ( _enquiries,
        _enquiries[_GUID] = _2018_Budget[_GUID] && _enquiries[Excluded] = TRUE()
    ),
    _enquiries[Amount (Enq)]
)
```